# Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, could not initialize proxy - no Session through reference chain

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting this error.I don't know what is this error and how to solve it.

Error:-

```
Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.neostencil.modules.testmanagement.model.entities.question.Question.options, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.neostencil.modules.testmanagement.responses.question.FetchQuestionById[\"question\"]->com.neostencil.modules.testmanagement.model.entities.question.Question[\"options\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.neostencil.modules.testmanagement.model.entities.question.Question.options, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.neostencil.modules.testmanagement.responses.question.FetchQuestionById[\"question\"]->com.neostencil.modules.testmanagement.model.entities.question.Question[\"options\"])"
```

I am using @ElementCollection to store List of string.This is my entity model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
public class Question extends DomainObject {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "question_gen")
@TableGenerator(name = "question_gen", table = "ns_question_id_gen", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "QuestionId_Gen", initialValue = 10000, allocationSize = 100)
@Id
@Column(name = "question_id")
private int questionId;

@Column(name = "question_text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "question_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private QuestionType type;

@Column(name = "question_timeout")
private Double timeout;

@Column(name = "marks")
private Double marks;

@Column(name = "negative_mark")
private Double negativeMark;

@Column(name = "question_position")
private Double position;

@ElementCollection()
@CollectionTable(name = "ns_question_option_items",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"))
@Column(name = "question_options")
public List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> getOptions() {
    return options;
}
public void setOptions(List<String> options) {
    this.options = options;
}

@Column(name = "subject")
private String subject;

@Column(name = "test_id")
private BigInteger testId;

public BigInteger getTestId() {
    return testId;
}


public void setTestId(BigInteger testId) {
    this.testId = testId;
}

public Question() {
    super();
}

public Question(int questionId, String questionText, QuestionType questionType, Double questionTimeout, Double marks, Double negativeMark, Double questionPosition, List<String> questionOptions, String subject, Answer answer) {
    super();
    this.questionId = questionId;
    this.text = questionText;
    this.type = questionType;
    this.timeout = questionTimeout;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.negativeMark = negativeMark;
    this.position = questionPosition;
    this.options = questionOptions;
    this.subject = subject;


}

public Question(String createdBy, Timestamp creationDate, int version, Timestamp lastModifiedDate,
                String lastModifiedBy, RecordStatus recordStatus) {
    super(createdBy, creationDate, version, lastModifiedDate, lastModifiedBy, recordStatus);
}

public int getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public QuestionType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(QuestionType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Double getTimeout() {
    return timeout;
}

public void setTimeout(Double timeout) {
    this.timeout = timeout;
}

public Double getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public void setMarks(Double marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
}

public Double getNegativeMark() {
    return negativeMark;
}

public void setNegativeMark(Double negativeMark) {
    this.negativeMark = negativeMark;
}

public Double getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(Double position) {
    this.position = position;
}





public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
}
```

I am getting this error while fetching Question model from a table using question id.This is my function where I am fetching Question

```
public Question fetchQuestionById(int id) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Question question = session.get(Question.class, new Integer(id));
    List<String> options = question.getOptions();

    question.setOptions(options);
    session.close();
    return question;
}
```

I am using Postgres database. I want to store a list of string in the database so that I am using @ElementCollection annotation for that. I am searched on the internet but found nothing. What is the problem here?Is the correct approach to store list of string in the database? If not, please tell me and what is the solution of above probelm.

Comment: Usually that means that the Session you used to load question with is already closed when trying to access options... are you sure the error happen in the fetchQuestionById-Method and not afterwards?

Comment: @tom I don't know but the question is storing in a correct way.How to check that because every time I am closing the session and creating a new session.